# How to get subtitles of a video QML

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

How to get video subtitles(captions) in qml?
like here Gnome Videos does
[image]

Comment: subtitles are in seperate file and you can read that file

Comment: but in my case it's a single '.mkv file which has multipe audio tracks and subtitles

Comment: add `import os` `os.environ["QT_GSTREAMER_PLAYBIN_FLAGS"] = str(0x00000017)` before QGuiApplication

Comment: i want to toggle it on and of